# Checking files differences before an update

Tags: apt, updates

Like most Ubuntu systems, I have updates checking turned on. So, eventually, I have a batch of updates to decide, select and allow.

Is there some quick (or, at least, good) way to effectively check what has changed *before* I update?

I've tried checking <strike>Launchpad</strike> `packages.ubuntu.com` for a given package (in my example, `zsh-doc`), I could find changelogs, package versions, but not a diff.

What I would really like to do is to check (on file contents level) what has changed from my installed version.

I don't have this curiosity on most of the updates, I just allow most of them. But sometimes it seems nice to know exactly what has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of one way to find the diffs on Launchpad:

**First**, locate the project page on Launchpad.

Example: Unattended Upgrades is at
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades

**Next**, at the bottom of the page are the various releases. Look for the release that you are interested in, and expand it. The diffs used are in the release details.

Example: The diffs used in Unattended Upgrades 1.5 are at
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/1.5ubuntu2

Comment: Thank you so much, @user535733! In fact, I've found out I've provided wrong info - I was checking packages.ubuntu.com, not LaunchPad. :-(